# HP TouchSmart 520 won't enter boot menu

Tags: boot, bios, hp-pavilion

I got my hands on HP TouchSmart 520 which runs Windows 10.

It won't boot past the screen below. From the web I've gathered
that HP boot menu should come up after holding F10. It won't though.

The only way the computer reacts to different function keys pressed upon start is when I press <kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>F9</kbd>, <kbd>F10</kbd>, <kbd>F12</kbd>, <kbd>Windows Key</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and the only difference on the screen is "Start Up Menu", "Boot Menu", "Network Mode" displayed where you see "Diagnostics" on the picture below. But no options to choose from. Just the black screen with technical specs of the computer displayed.

I've tried to remove RAM and put back in, remove HDD and put back in, power-cycle the computer.

Swap HDD for another one (even though that shouldn't matter since I'm trying to get the computer to enter boot menu or BIOS).

[image: picture]

What else I can try ?

Comment: Get the HP Diagnostics App and make a bootable USB from that. Try to boot. If you cannot and in line with your tests above, the CPU or motherboard may have a fault.

Comment: @John  I've tried the HP's USB Diagnostic Tool for users who can't even boot and the computer didn't even launch the file from USB. I understand the program should launch automatically once the computer detects it. No luck.

Comment: What's frustrating is that the computer won't tell me what's wrong. Like error message "CPU failed" would be helpful.

Comment: You probably need to get the machine serviced at this point. It is a hardware issue

Comment: @John  Mate, I don't know what happened but the guy who brought the computer to me made it work again ! I was like "Are you joking me ??? BIOS wouldn't come up, the boot menu wouldn't come up. The computer was pretty much dead !" and now the computer works like nothing happened to it. When I asked what did he do to it he kept giving me secretive, avoiding answers. So I shook my head, said "Dude you're a magician" and walked off. I'm happy that the computer works again but what did he do to it is a great mystery.